# grails g:link pass params

Tags: grails, hyperlink, parameters

I have something like this:

```
<g:each in="${temp}">

  <li>Date: ${it.dateParticipated}, <br>Role: ${it.role}, <br>Acceptence: ${it.accepted}, <br>
  <g:link controller="conference" action="participated" id="${it.conference.id}">
     Conference: </g:link>${it.conference},<br>
Role: ${it.role}, <br>Status: ${it.status}</li><br>

  <br>
</g:each>
```

What i want to do is, when i click on 'Conference', the controller 'conference' with the method 'participated' is loaded, and the params 'it.conference' is passed. How can i pass this params in the g:link tag ?

I need this because, when i click in the 'conference' word, other page is loaded with the conference details with the id passed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the params attribute to pass in a map of parameters:

```
<g:link action="/conference/participated" id="${it.conference.id}" params="[foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo']">My Link!</g:link>
```

See [the documentation](http://www.grails.org/Tag%20-%20link) for more examples.

Comment: i read it. but i dont understand how can i pass 'it.conference' through it.

Comment: Is conference a full-fledged object or a primitive?

Comment: It's not terribly obvious from the documentation but you drop the quote marks to refer to a variable set in the previous action

Comment: @barrymac thanks for that one, never would have guessed. It works, but it's incredibly ugly and IDEA even reports it as a syntax error, so if anyone has a better idea... ;) Example for future readers: params="[foo: "${it.bar}"]"

Comment: This way might be a little less ugly... :) `params="${[foo:it.bar]}"`

Comment: might be less ugly, but it didn't produce the params for me.

Answer (score 6):

You need to wrap your entire params with ${ }, instead of wrapping every variable that you want to pass separately.

```
<g:each in="${temp}">

  <li>Date: ${it.dateParticipated}, <br>Role: ${it.role}, <br>Acceptence: ${it.accepted}, <br>
  <g:link controller="conference" action="participated" params="${[id: it.conference.id, role: it.role, status: it.status]}">
     Conference: </g:link>

  <br>
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
params="[customerId: customer.id]"
```

Comment: heelo bro i have used the same annotation but i am getting null value in controller https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855362/not-able-to-pass-the-id-to-the-controller-from-gsp