# Not able to pass the ID to the controller from gsp

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I want to pass the id="${training.id}" to the Organization controller wiith the confirmed() function inside the controller.but when i am passing it,it is showing me the NULL result.The (id) i am printing is NULL.

gsp file

```
<g:each in="${trainingLists}" var="training">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Organization Name:</h3>${training.organization.orgName}</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3>Organization Description:</h3>${training.organization.orgDesc}</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3>Training Available:</h3>${training.name}</div>
    <sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
        <g:link controller="organization" action="notconfirmed">Apply</g:link>
    </sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
        <sec:ifLoggedIn>
            <g:link action="confirmed" id="${training.id}">Apply</g:link>
        </sec:ifLoggedIn>
    </div>
    <br>
</g:each>
```

Organization.controller

```
def confirmed(){
        def id = params.id
        println(id)

    }
```

Comment: what url shown in address bar after click on Apply button?

Comment: i havent put any url there it must go through the Organization controller and there is confirmed() function inside

Comment: while clicking apply button the id is not passed

Comment: yeah that's i am asking.  URL does not show id

Comment: the url shown is "localhost:8080/organization/confirmed";

Comment: please try to print `${training.id}` and check is it have id

Comment: no while jsut putting <h3>Training id:${training.id}</h3> it is not printing anything

Comment: Yes it means `${trainingLists}` objects does not have id, so please check it first. Check my posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gsp `<g:link>` looks good.

Please debug and check is `${training.id}` have valid id.

```
<g:link controller="organization" action="confirmed" id="${training.id}">Apply</g:link>
```

still getting issue then temporary hard-code id to  and check 
for Example:

```
<g:link controller="organization" action="confirmed" id="2">Apply</g:link>
```

Now in address bar you will URL like `localhost:8080/organization/confirmed/2` and controller println also print the 2.

You can check [documentation](https://gsp.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/link.html) for more attributes and options

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows.

```
<g:link action="confirmed" params="[id: training.id]">Apply</g:link>

def confirmed(){
        def id = params.id
        println "Training Id: "+id

}
```

Comment: Verify first is training.id has value or not